# Linux packets going to strange interfaces when NATing between bridges

Tags: linux, networking, nat, bridge

I have a desktop computer (Ubuntu 19.10) running containers and VMs. Its ethernet `enp2s0` is bridged with systemd-networkd:

```
[Match]
Name=enp2s0

[Network]
Bridge=bridge
LinkLocalAddressing=no
```

The bridge interface is named exactly `bridge` and has IP addresses when shown with `ip a`, for example, `192.168.1.2/24`. It also has a wireless interface `wlp3s0` with IP address `192.168.5.2/24` and an OpenVPN interface `ovpn` at `10.0.1.2/24`.

My containers and VMs are running under an internal bridge `virbr0` where the host has the address `172.17.0.1/16`. The strange thing is, no container or VM can reach the network outside host interface `bridge`, but all of them can reach anything from host interfaces `wlp3s0` (e.g. `192.168.5.1`) and `ovpn` (e.g. `10.0.1.1`).

I tried pinging different locations from a VM and watching packets on the host.

```
root@iBug-Server:~# tcpdump -leni bridge icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on bridge, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:05:36.068658 86:80:93:9a:83:87 > d8:67:d9:70:e9:41, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.1.2 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6227, seq 1, length 64
00:05:36.068902 d8:67:d9:70:e9:41 > 86:80:93:9a:83:87, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.2: ICMP echo reply, id 6227, seq 1, length 64
00:05:36.068930 86:80:93:9a:83:87 > d8:67:d9:70:e9:41, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.1.1 > 172.17.2.120: ICMP echo reply, id 6227, seq 1, length 64
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
root@iBug-Server:~# tcpdump -leni wlp3s0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on wlp3s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:06:29.306316 12:04:21:2d:39:18 > 74:f8:db:6a:3e:d1, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.5.2 > 192.168.5.1: ICMP echo request, id 6231, seq 1, length 64
00:06:29.317283 74:f8:db:6a:3e:d1 > 12:04:21:2d:39:18, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.5.1 > 192.168.5.2: ICMP echo reply, id 6231, seq 1, length 64
^C
2 packets captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
root@iBug-Server:~# tcpdump -leni enp2s0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:09:12.098863 86:80:93:9a:83:87 > d8:67:d9:70:e9:41, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.1.2 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6232, seq 1, length 64
00:09:12.099100 d8:67:d9:70:e9:41 > 86:80:93:9a:83:87, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.1.1 > 192.168.1.2: ICMP echo reply, id 6232, seq 1, length 64
00:09:12.099145 86:80:93:9a:83:87 > d8:67:d9:70:e9:41, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.1.1 > 172.17.2.120: ICMP echo reply, id 6232, seq 1, length 64
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

As can be seen above, the 3rd packet from `bridge` or `enp2s0` appears to be going to the wrong place (it should have been to `virbr0`) and also having wrong MAC addresses. Here are the results from `virbr0`. Note how the ICMP reply didn't appear when pinging `192.168.1.1` (gateway of host's `bridge` interface).

```
root@iBug-Server:~# tcpdump -leni virbr0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on virbr0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:21:49.815124 00:16:3e:03:1a:f8 > 52:b4:4b:3f:45:e2, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.17.2.120 > 192.168.1.1: ICMP echo request, id 6238, seq 1, length 64
^C
1 packet captured
1 packet received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
root@iBug-Server:~# tcpdump -leni virbr0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on virbr0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
00:21:59.268210 00:16:3e:03:1a:f8 > 52:b4:4b:3f:45:e2, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.17.2.120 > 192.168.5.1: ICMP echo request, id 6239, seq 1, length 64
00:21:59.277884 52:b4:4b:3f:45:e2 > 00:16:3e:03:1a:f8, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 192.168.5.1 > 172.17.2.120: ICMP echo reply, id 6239, seq 1, length 64
^C
2 packets captured
2 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

My iptables has an empty FORWARD chain with policy ACCEPT, and I didn't touch the `nat` table after setting up KVM (with libvirt). What's going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So stupid of me!

I wanted to make sure packets coming from the ethernet interface go the same way back, so I had these lines among my startup scripts:

```
ip rule add dev bridge table 1
ip route add table 1 default via 192.168.1.1 dev bridge
```

This is causing the NAT'd ICMP reply packet going back to the `bridge` interface.

To solve this, copy everything necessary from the main table:

```
ip route add table 1 192.168.5.0/24 dev wlp3s0
ip route add table 1 172.17.0.0/16 dev virbr0
... and so on
```